# How does dbeaver programatically export data as .sql files?

Tags: python, export, dbeaver

I'm building a python app that that can help authorised users to retrieve sample data from production mysql databases to cloud data stores for auditing and tracking purposes. I'm able provide data as CSV files.

However, the auditors now need to import this data into databases in SQL format. For this, I'm currently exporting the query results manually into [SQL format](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2153#:%7E:text=You%20can%20export%20a%20table,INSERT%20statements%22%20format%20and%20voila.) using Dbeaver so that it can be ingested by the users by executing the .sql files. It will be great if I can use any libraries that enable this feature in my app.

I tried searching the [Dbeaver code base](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver) to check for any libraries but could not identify. Please suggest if these is a smarter pythonic way to achieve this?